# Could not install package 'SharpCompress 0.32.2'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PW4y.png)**

- Issue:-

** Could not install package 'SharpCompress 0.32.2'.
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references
or content files that are compatible with that framework.
For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: v4.61 is the [minimum supported version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpCompress/0.30.1#supportedframeworks-body-tab).  Targeting v4.5 makes very little sense today, so bump that up.  Best to pick the version you have on your machine, that ought to be v4.8

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the net framework version of your project.
In visual studio go to solution explorer -> right click on the project -> "Application" -> change the net framework version 4.6.1 (atleast)